# Posizione di "sempre" quando è accompagnato da un verbo

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Nel linguaggio comune, quando l'avverbio "sempre" è accompagnato da un verbo, deve esso seguire necessariamente al verbo? O si può anche scrivere "sempre" prima del verbo? Ad esempio, nella frase

> Ho sempre la curiosità di sapere se c'è qualche novità interessante nel mondo della cultura

ho messo "sempre" dopo il verbo. Sarebbe anche corretto scrivere "sempre" prima del verbo, in questo modo?

> Sempre ho la curiosità di sapere se c'è qualche novità interessante nel mondo della cultura.

Comment: *Sempre ho* sembra poco comune; viceversa, *spesso ho* oppure *raramente ho* sono frequenti. Analogamente, *mai* è di solito posposto (con un *non* rafforzativo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

È meglio mettere "sempre" dopo il verbo (esempio: “mi fermo sempre all'edicola quando esco per andare al lavoro”). Metterlo prima suona molto enfatico: va bene solo nelle poesie, nelle canzoni, nelle opere teatrali...

Answer (score 2):

> Sempre caro mi fu quest'ermo colle

è l'inizio di una bella e famosa poesia, ma qui parliamo del linguaggio comune.

L'avverbio “sempre” è normalmente posposto al verbo:

> ho sempre la curiosità di sapere …

e lo stesso vale per *mai* che però attira il *non* rafforzativo:

> non ho mai la curiosità di sapere …

Il modo *sempre ho* oppure *mai ho* è, a quanto mi risulta, in via di sparizione se già non è sparito, a parte linguaggi settoriali (leggi, burocrazia) o la poesia. Forse *mai ho* è meno infrequente. Entrambi corretti, sia chiaro, ma desueti.

Nota che gli avverbi “approssimativi” (termine certamente non tecnico) come *raramente* o *spesso* vanno indifferentemente prima o dopo, dando sfumature diverse:

> raramente ho la curiosità di sapere …
>
> ho raramente la curiosità di sapere …

potrebbero suggerire interpretazioni leggermente differenti, ma si tratta, come detto, di sfumature.